# Cannot start session in PHP on ARM

Tags: php, arm, embedded-linux

I have PHP installed on ARM91. It works fine until I use session_start. Then I get the following
Warning: session_start(): read returned less bytes than requested
This does not seem to be a permission problem - the sess_* files are created. When you try to put anything into such session, it creates sparse file (17GB size) for the session with real size 12 bytes (exactly what i wanted to write there). Doing strace I think the problem is somewhere in **__llseek** that cause creation of such huge sparse file. I have similar issue with SQLITE (cannot open any DB, disk I/O error but i can cat the DB file and also seems it's llseek issue when creating DB journal file). I have no idea where to look further or how to solve that, fail to google any similar reports.

Comment: Looks like signed/unsigned bug in particular PHP implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it was issue of incompatible uclibc. After recompiling everything with carefully reviewed settings it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something worthy of reporting to the PHP bug tracker.

If nothing comes up that helps, you could roll your own session storage functions using **[session_save_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)**. If you check out the manual page, there is an example for a complete alternative rewrite of the file based session handler.